# Slicing NaN values before first and after last occurrence for every time series in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, slice

I work on time series in Python 3 and Pandas. I have a dataframe with multiple time series (in this example two), each time series contains sales data for one shop. The dataframe looks like:

```
                  index  Shop  Quantity
index Date                             
0     2017-01-08      0     1       NaN
1     2017-01-15      1     1       NaN
2     2017-01-22      2     1      34.0
3     2017-01-29      3     1      54.0
4     2017-02-05      4     1      42.0
5     2017-02-12      5     1       NaN
6     2017-01-08      6     2       NaN
7     2017-01-15      7     2      29.0
8     2017-01-22      8     2       NaN
9     2017-01-29      9     2      58.0
10    2017-02-05     10     2      49.0
11    2017-02-12     11     2       NaN
```

For every time series, I want to drop the NaNs until the first occurrence and the NaNs after the last occurrence. It should look similar to:

```
                  index  Shop  Quantity
index Date                             
2     2017-01-22      2     1      34.0
3     2017-01-29      3     1      54.0
4     2017-02-05      4     1      42.0
7     2017-01-15      7     2      29.0
8     2017-01-22      8     2       NaN
9     2017-01-29      9     2      58.0
10    2017-02-05     10     2      49.0
```

However, the following code drops the NaNs before the overall first and after the overall last occurrence, but not the lines with index 5 and 6:

```
df = df.loc[df['Quantity'].first_valid_index():df['Quantity'].last_valid_index()]
```

```
                  index  Shop  Quantity
index Date                             
2     2017-01-22      2     1      34.0
3     2017-01-29      3     1      54.0
4     2017-02-05      4     1      42.0
5     2017-02-12      5     1       NaN
6     2017-01-08      6     2       NaN
7     2017-01-15      7     2      29.0
8     2017-01-22      8     2       NaN
9     2017-01-29      9     2      58.0
10    2017-02-05     10     2      49.0
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `groupby` and `first_valid_index` and `last_valid_index` with index slicing using `loc`:

```
df.groupby('Shop', group_keys=False)\
  .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Quantity'].first_valid_index():x['Quantity'].last_valid_index()])
```

Output:

```
                  ind  Shop  Quantity
index Date                           
2     2017-01-22    2     1      34.0
3     2017-01-29    3     1      54.0
4     2017-02-05    4     1      42.0
7     2017-01-15    7     2      29.0
8     2017-01-22    8     2       NaN
9     2017-01-29    9     2      58.0
10    2017-02-05   10     2      49.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
l = df.index[~(df['Date']>df['Date'].shift())].to_list()
l.append(len(df))
l_mod = [0] + l + [max(l)+1]
list_of_dfs = [df.iloc[l_mod[n]:l_mod[n+1]] for n in range(len(l_mod)-1)]

df_new=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for d in list_of_dfs:
    df_new = df_new.append(d.loc[d['Quantity'].first_valid_index():d['Quantity'].last_valid_index()])
df_new

         Date index.1 Shop  Quantity
2  2017-01-22       2    1      34.0
3  2017-01-29       3    1      54.0
4  2017-02-05       4    1      42.0
7  2017-01-15       7    2      29.0
8  2017-01-22       8    2       NaN
9  2017-01-29       9    2      58.0
10 2017-02-05      10    2      49.0
```